# Shall a HTTP DELETE request reset the resource-list's cache?

Tags: rest, http, caching, get, request

We're building a REST API and ran into the following problem:

1. GET /items > [a,b,c] # (max-age 120 seconds)
2. GET /items/a > status 200
3. DELETE /items/a
4. GET /items/a > status 404
5. GET /items > [**a**,b,c] # as it's cached

So the resource list still contains item **a** as it was cached before. Our clients only support invalidation on the exact URI, not the parent's.

Is this a design issue of on our side or should a DELETE request maybe also expire the parent resource's cache?